# Associate FTP hyperlink to filezilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla, protocol

Is it possible to associate a link like ftp://myftpserver.net to launch automatically Filezilla and display the FTP server content with one click?
I think there must be a kind of protocol registration which is currently associate with my Web browser.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: xp, vista and 7. I need a general solution!

Comment: there won't be a general solution since the OS handle this differently....

Comment: I have the same question about Win8 at http://superuser.com/questions/634881/associate-ftp-links-with-filezilla-in-win8-or-any-specific-exe-with-a-protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Windows XP**

1. Open an explorer window (any folder or drive)
2. Click Tools->Folder options
3. Click "File Types" tab
4. Find "URL:File Transfer Protocol" towards the top of the list
5. Select "Change" at the bottom and browse to the filezilla executable

**EDIT:**

For Win 7 - I do not have a copy to test on, but it will (hopefully) be here:

1. Control Panel
2. Control Panel Home
3. Default Programs
4. Set Associations

See if there is something similar to the **"URL:File Transfer Protocol"** listed above for XP.  If so, click "Change Program" and associate it with FileZilla.

Comment: It may work on XP but I'm using Windows 7...

Comment: @Tinmaru - see the edit.

Comment: Answer accepted but in fact it doesn't work on my computer: I don't have other choice than Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome. It is maybe due to my IT policies.

Comment: @tinmaru - you can't specify an exe?

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows 10**

1. Go to Settings -> Apps -> Default apps -> Choose defaults apps by
   protocol.
2. Under "FTP URL:File Transfer Protocol", click the item in the
       "Default app" column.
3. Windows will provide a list of browsers, or allow you to look for an
       app in the Windows Store, but provides no way to choose Filezilla.
4. Swear at the screen.
5. Follow the extremely complex instructions at
       https://web.archive.org/web/20141228000828/https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=13297
6. You can now open ftp links with Filezilla.

Comment: Dear Microsoft, could you please burn in hell ....

Comment: Tried using those .reg files (removing the " (x86)") but it didn't work for me.