# Associate FTP links with FileZilla in Win8 (or any specific exe with a protocol)

Tags: windows-8, ftp, file-association

Like [Associate FTP hyperlink to filezilla](https://superuser.com/questions/186563/associate-ftp-hyperlink-to-filezilla), I want to associate FTP links with FileZilla, only I'm on Windows 8. When I open an FTP link or try to set the associated app for FTP links, I don't get an option to just browse for any executable (nor do I get a specific entry for FileZilla; see screenshot).

Anyone know how to get FileZilla associated with FTP links on Win8? Or how to associate any particular exe with a file type/protocol?

[image: File association for FTP showing browsers but not FileZilla]

I tried the app described at [Specify a custom program for handling a protocol](https://superuser.com/questions/189742/specify-a-custom-program-for-handling-a-protocol) but it just registered FTP links with IE.